# Scope issue when iterating through a hash map

Tags: java, scope, hashmap

I guess I have a fairly simple question. I have two double arrays and a hash map.

```
double[] x
double[] y
HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> myList;
```

I'd like to get the values for each key and find a summation by using those values in two arrays. However, I keep receiving the scope error. `"...defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"`

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   if ( .... ) {
        double sum = 0; 
        myList.get(i).forEach((val) -> { 
          sum = sum + x[val] + y[val];
        });

        if (sum >= ...) {

        }
}
```

I placed the variable `sum` in different places, but could not figure out what I am doing wrong. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: @Deadpool  Thanks!  I got my answer from that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get this issue with any primitive type. Change your `sum` from primitive to some other Object type, where you won't change the reference but can change the value.

For example, it can be a `double[1]` double array of size 1, then change value at 0th index, Or, `AtomicDouble` where you can set the value.

Answer (score 0):

local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final.
[Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables)

Here is my solution:

```
    double[] x = new double[] {10.0, 20.0};
    double[] y = new double[] {30.0, 40.0};

    HashMap<Integer, double[]> myList = new HashMap<>();
    myList.put(0, x);
    myList.put(1, y);

    double sum = myList.keySet().stream().map(myList::get)
    .map(doubleArr -> Arrays.stream(doubleArr).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b))
    .reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> a + b);

    System.out.println("Result = " + sum);
```